# Make Windows partition as /home partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, windows, home-directory

After 4 months of running Ubuntu alongside Windows, I'd like to remove Win to make the partition where is installed as /home partition.

I had Windows "just in case something goes wrong" but I think, if ever something will go wrong, I could just reinstall Ubuntu (if I can't fix it), having a dedicated /home partition will make my life easier because I wouldn't need to backup my files.

Is there any procedure or best practice to follow in order to do a good job?

Comment: You ALWAYS need to have backups.

Comment: Only if your data & time is not valuable, do you not need backups. Your /home will need to be Linux formatted often ext4. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: Having a separate /home makes life easier, backups of important data is still a must.  Just need to drop computer or spill liquid on it, to ruin your day.  Make sure Win partition is big enough, don't want a small size.  Format it to ext4 and then search for separating /home from /.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you do need a backup, anytime, because hardware can fail and human error can occur. However, you probably intended to say that there would be no need to erase the data and put it back if you have a separate home partition.

Doing so on your current system is a little technical. Somewhat easier, but still a bit technical, would be to reinstall Ubuntu, then choose "Something else" and then assign your root `/` and `/home` partition yourself. Then the installer would take care of the formatting and system configuration.

If you prefer modifying your current system, then start by reformatting the former Windows partition to `ext4`. Using [a stepwise approach](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) from the Ubuntu documentation team, you can then move your current home partition to that new `ext4` partition.

Comment: that's what I thought, however, I believe that I need to reinstall and configure all the applications as well, which I wanted to avoid but it's not a big deal.